# Exchange principle in terms of states and coordinates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fermions, bosons

I have seen the exchange principle written in two ways, one in terms of coordinates and the other in terms of states:

> If $\psi_{AB}(1,2)$ represents particle $A$ in state $1$ and particle $B$ in state $2$ then for bosons:
>   $$\psi_{AB}(1,2)=\psi_{AB}(2,1)$$ and for fermions: $$\psi_{AB}(1,2)=-\psi_{AB}(2,1)$$

and

> If $\psi_{AB}(\vec x_1, \vec x_2)$ represents particle $A$ at $\vec x_1$ and particle $B$ at $\vec x_2$ then for bosons:
>   $$\psi_{AB}(\vec x_1,\vec x_2)=\psi_{AB}(\vec x_2,\vec x_1)$$ and for fermions: $$\psi_{AB}(\vec x_1,\vec x_2)=-\psi_{AB}(\vec x_2,\vec x_1)$$

Do both these tell us the exactly same information (i.e. may one hold when the other doesn't) and can this be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first convention, by state they mean *total state* (including *spatial* and *spin* components) but for the second convention, by state they mean *only* spatial component. This means that the first convention has *more* information and hence *more* restrictive. Particles can be at the *same place* (following the second convention) yet have *different spin* states (not following the first convention). So, the second convention is a subset of the first convention by being less restrictive.

By the end of the day, however, *fermions* should have an *antisymmetric total state* and *bosons* should have a *symmetric total state.*

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the vector $\vec{x}$ includes spin coordinates. 
The coordinate itself is an observable which has a continuum spectrum. So a coordinate operator has eigenvalues that characterize a state. So there is no much difference between the first and second definition, since instead of saying an electron has a coordinate $x$, we can also say that the electron is in the state $x$.